# Mastercard Hosted Checkout Integration

Tags: payment, mastercard

I am trying to integrate the hosted checkout with MasterCard. I would like to provide a complete callback URL  to the payment request. According to the documentation, for your callback to be notified on payment success/failure, you should create a session and provide the session id in the checkout.configure object. I have been able to generate the session but when i pass the session id, i get the following error when i try to pay.

```
{
    "cause": "INVALID_REQUEST",
    "explanation": "Value '46' is invalid. The version used for this request must match the version previously used to update the session using the UPDATE_SESSION operation or OPEN_WALLET operation.",
    "field": "version",
    "validationType": "INVALID"
}
```

Kindly assist if you can.

Comment: Can you include a link to MasterCard's documentation that you mention in the question?

Comment: @ajmccall [Mastercard MPGS documentation](https://na-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a session using `Create Checkout Session` operation. For this operation, the API URL would be:
`https://na-gateway.mastercard.com/api/nvp/version/<version-number>`.

The version number in the above URL must match the version number in the `checkout.js` file:

```
 <script src="https://na-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/<version-number>/checkout.js"
            data-error="errorCallback"
            data-cancel="cancelCallback">
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the issue. It has worked!

Comment: @ザヘド i'm having trouble integrating this api in deno... it's not clear why i should refer to the checkout.js url in the html, and use another url to send the data!!!